# Como asignar permisos a un grupo en Linux por consola [Linux]

Tags: linux, bash, script

La cuestión es la siguiente:
Tengo que crear una carpeta compartida en el mismo PC para los encargados y los empleados.
Los encargados tienen que tener permiso de lectura y escritura en los archivos de la carpeta, por el contrario los empleados únicamente pueden tener permiso de lectura.
Para ello he creado 2 grupos con

```
sudo addgroup trabajadores
sudo addgroup empleados
```

Luego he agregado a cada empleado a su grupo

```
sudo adduser <nombre-empleado> trabajadores
```

Y he hecho lo mismo con los encargados

```
sudo adduser <nombre-encargado> encargados
```

La carpeta la he creado en /home por lo que para que los empleados y los encargados puedan acceder a ella le he creado un enlace simbólico de esta manera:

```
sudo ln -s /home/<carpeta-compartida> /home/<nombre-empleado>/Escritorio
```

La cosa es que no se como asignarse a cada grupo sus permisos.
Con que comando se hace? Si alguien puede poner algún ejemplo se lo agradecería mucho.
Saludos

Comment: [Aquí](https://www.google.com/search?q=Cu%C3%A1l+es+la+forma+de+asignar+permisos+a+los+grupos+de+Linux%3F+Es+decir+con+que+comando+se+hace%3F+Si+pod%C3%A9is+poner+alg%C3%BAn+ejemplo+os+lo+agradezco+%21) lo explican muy bien.  Por favor, léete [ask], [tour] y [example] para realizar buenas preguntas, gracias.

Comment: @masterguru ya he modificado la pregunta, a ver si me podeis echar una mano. Antes la he escrito desde el móvil rápidamente porque no tenía tiempo.

Comment: Es un poco complejo de responder sin soltarte todo un rollo.  Mejor que aprendas lo básico aquí primero: https://docs.bluehosting.cl/tutoriales/servidores/conceptos-basicos-sobre-permisos-y-propiedades-en-linux.html y después, cuando entiendas lo del propietario (owner), grupo (group) y el resto del mundo podrás utilizar `chmod` y `chown` para ello sobre la carpeta y sus archivos.